# what is the best practices for the markup structure for a pagination?

Tags: html

What should be the best precise markup for a pagination structure? should be tables?, div or span?, simple links or other?

**NAV STYLE**

```
<nav>
  <a href="#1">1</a>
  <a href="#1">2</a>
  <a href="#1">3</a>
</nav>
```

**LIST STYLE**

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

**TABLE STYLE or other?**

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I think now we have html5 should be `<nav>` plus `<a>` but I'm not sure...

Comment: Using table for style is now highly not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            ...
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It makes semantic sense and it's easy to style.

Comment: in semantic way why don't simple remove the list and use anchors? <nav><a>1</a></nav>?

Answer (score 1):

For semantical goodness, use `nav` as the outer tag. The links should be `a` tags, but they don't need to be immediate children of `nav`. You can use lists, tables, or plain links; as long as `a` tags are found under `nav`.